# Parse Arguments to Lua File

Tags: lua

I have File: data.lua

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua
local a = {
    b = {
        c = {
            version = "z.y"
        },
        d = {
            version = "z.w"

        },
        getcversion = function ( self )
            print( self.c.version )
        end
    }
}
```

Now I need to 'getcversion()' Function..

```
a.b:getcversion()
```

The problem is, I need to call it from the outside:

```
data.lua "a.b:getcversion()"
```

I tried everything that I could, but I couldn't solve this..

Does any one knows how I could call 'getcversion()' ?

Thanks in Advance,
Regards

Comment: Hi perhaps try this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Programming/command_line_parameter

Comment: what is "outside" ? another Lua file?

Comment: Outside its a bash script that calls that file: data.lua "a.b:getcversion()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add something like the following to your script:

```
load(arg[1], "<string>", "t", {a = a})()
```

`load` will load the content of the passed parameter (`arg[1]`) and will return the function that will execute that code in a specific environment (provided as `{a = a}` table), as you need to pass the values of local variables to your code (Lua 5.2+).

Keep in mind that this will allow the caller to pass arbitrary Lua code to your script, which may be a security issue.

The error handling is left as the exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this..  `load (chunk [, chunkname [, mode [, env]]])`  Its a answer to the problem :)  I will stick for now with:  `load( arg[1] .. "()", arg[1] .. "()", "t", {a = a} )()`.  With this, I can call from bash without escaping parenthesises "\\(\\)", in this way: 
 `data.lua a.b:getcversion`  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add `return a` to the end of data.lua to turn it into a module, and then:

```
$ lua -e 'a = require("data"); print(a.b:getcversion())'
z.y
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  yet another solution, that I didn't knew off :)